# How would I find the key in a dictionary from a value?

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary:

```
thisdict = {
  "1": ['Vanilla','Chocolate']
  "2": ['Vanilla']
  "7": ['Chocolate']
  "8": ['Chocolate','Vanilla']
}
```

Note: The numbers are ID Numbers.

I want to input the values: ['Vanilla','Chocolate'] and get all keys, regardless of order where the values occur.

So all I would want it to return is:

["1","8"]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily check equality by comparing values as sets (that will solve sorting problem).

```
thisdict = {
  "1": ['Vanilla','Chocolate'],
  "2": ['Vanilla'],
  "7": ['Chocolate'],
  "8": ['Chocolate','Vanilla'],
}
x = {'Vanilla','Chocolate'}

keys = [k for k, v in thisdict.items() if set(v) == x]
print(keys)  # -> ['1', '8']
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dict is no longer than this and you only have to do this search every once in a while, Filip Młynarski's "brute force" solution is probably good enough.

If it's much longer and you have to do a lot of searches on it (the dict remaining unchanged between searches), you may want to build a "reverse index" instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict
thisdict = {
  "1": ['Vanilla','Chocolate'],
  "2": ['Vanilla'],
  "7": ['Chocolate'],
  "8": ['Chocolate','Vanilla'],
}
rev = defaultdict(list)
for key, values in thisdict.items():
    rev[frozenset(values)].append(key)

x = frozenset(('Vanilla','Chocolate'))
keys = rev[x]
print(keys)
```

The point is to know whether the overhead of building this reverse index will be compensated for by the (possibly huge) lookup performances gain, and this depends on your concrete data set and use case.